# routeconfig.cs - page doesnot exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my routeconfig.cs

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Background/AutoComplete.aspx/{*webmethod}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Background/Misc.aspx");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "NoAuthorName",
          url: "Author",
          defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AuthorNameonly",
           url: "{controller}/{author}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "AllQuotesByAuthorWithoutAuthorID" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AuthorNamewithAuthorID",
            url: "{controller}/{author}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "AllQuotesByAuthorWithAuthorID"});

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AllQuotesByAuthorWithAuthorIDandQuoteID",
          url: "{controller}/{author}/{id}/{id1}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "AllQuotesByAuthorWithAuthorIDandQuoteID" });

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "FinalURLwithAuthor",
        url: "{controller}/{author}/{id}/{id1}/{quotesseparatedbyhyphen}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "Finalurl" });


        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "NoKeywordName",
         url: "Keyword",
         defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID",
          url: "{controller}/{key}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID" });

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID",
           url: "{controller}/{key}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID" });


        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This is how it  works.
http://sitename.com/Author/Benjamin-Quotes/AuthorID - works.

http://sitename.com/Author/Benjamin-Quotes/ - works.

http://sitename.com/Author - works.

but

http://sitename.com/Keyword - works

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love - **doesnot work**   `404. error`

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love/Keywordid - **doesnot work.**  `404. error`

However when i remove all map routes for author and have only for keyword like this in routeconfig.cs

```
  routes.MapRoute(
         name: "NoKeywordName",
         url: "Keyword",
         defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID",
          url: "{controller}/{key}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID" });

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID",
           url: "{controller}/{key}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID" });


        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

now http://sitename.com/Keyword - works

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love - works

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love/Keywordid - works.

Now if I mix both author route and keyword route in routeconfig.cs 
the following url doesnot exist.HTTP  `404. error`

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love -

http://sitename.com/Keyword/Love/Keywordid - .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route patterns for both `AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID` and `AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID` are the same as those for `AuthorNameonly` and `AuthorNamewithAuthorID`, respectively. The fact that you're naming the route parameters differently is not enough to distinguish the routes from each other. As a result, the first one that matches wins, which in this case is `AuthorNameonly` and `AuthorNamewithAuthorID`. In other words, when you hit a route like `/Keyword/Love`, `Keyword` goes into `controller`, giving you the correct controller, *but*, `Love` is put into an `author` param, which your action on `KeywordController` will not be able to utilize, because it's looking for a `key` param. Further, since you're not specifying the action, the default action is being utilized, which for this route is `AllQuotesByAuthorWithoutAuthorID`, which is not even an action on `KeywordController`, hence your 404.

Long and short, you need something else to distinguish these routes from each other. You could potentially just change the routes to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AuthorNameonly",
    url: "author/{author}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "AllQuotesByAuthorWithoutAuthorID" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AuthorNamewithAuthorID",
    url: "author/{author}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Author", action = "AllQuotesByAuthorWithAuthorID"});
```

And

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID",
    url: "keyword/{key}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordwithoutKeywordID" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID",
    url: "keyword/{key}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Keyword", action = "AllQuotesByKeywordWithKeywordID" });
```

In other words, instead of letting the `controller` param be variable, you specify it explicitly. Now, each route will only match if that first part of the URL path matches, removing the ambiguity.